# Disabling OPTIONS request coming from Client Side Script

Tags: php, angular, apache, cors, preflight

How to disable the OPTIONS Request from Server Side Script(PHP)..?? As I have posted the data through angular which method as POST, an another method OPTIONS also found on server side by googling it is came to know that it is a mandatory on  CORS as preflight requests. Is there any way handle this type of OPTIONS from back end server side script such as PHP.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent the client from sending CORS request if the front and back server are not on the same domain. All browsers make CORS request if needed

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

If you disable the OPTIONS method server side, it means that CORS request won't work anymore, meaning that you'll have to have your angular front and your PHP API on the same domain for your website to work.

Comment: What the problem am facing is, when I try to post the data to API two calls are going to back end, one as OPTIONS and second one as normal POST, hence the data's are inserted multiple times which makes a lot of headache's. Is there any way to handle this problem?

Comment: Make sure that in your PHP, if the current request's method is `OPTIONS`, then just return the CORS headers and do nothing else